# Do I need an US Visa if I have a traffic caution?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program

I am currently planning a round the world trip and intend to be entering the USA at LAX coming from Fiji.  I was involved in an accidental traffic collision in the UK and received a caution for careless driving.

I was never arrested or convicted but I'm not sure whether I can still travel on the ESTA form or if I need to get a visa.  When I emailed the embassy I was directed to a checklist to see if I was eligible to get access and it seemed like I could go with the ESTA, but it also makes a point that the tool is just a guide and not definite confirmation that the ESTA is ok.

So does anyone know, or been in this kind of situation, whether or not I need to get a visa?  Or should I try calling the embassy and see what they say, even though they are more likely to encourage applying for the visa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you haven't paid the fine and now have a warrant outstanding I wouldn't worry about it.

Traffic offenses are only a concern if you have committed something serious like a vehicular manslaughter or if you basically ignored the summons or mandatory court appearance and now have a warrant issued for your arrest.

[CBP discusses the subject of crimes](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1074/~/esta-application-denied) but also provides you with the link to the definitinon of crimes for which your [ESTA be denied](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/86942.pdf).  The list is too big to copy here but the only thing that involves vehicles is in fact manslaughter:

> Involuntary, where the statute requires proof of recklessness, which is defined as the awareness and conscious disregard of a substantial and unjustified risk which constitutes a gross deviation from the standard that a reasonable person would observe in the situation. A conviction for the statutory offense of vehicular homicide or other involuntary manslaughter that only requires a showing of negligence will not involve moral turpitude even if it appears the defendant in fact acted recklessly

Comment: Ok that's great! Thanks very much.  As you can imagine it's been a big worry as I don't want the end of my world trip to be denied entry for a stupid mistake.

Thanks for the speedy and detailed response :D